# Cypress tests failing in firefox in pages with polling requests

Tags: firefox, cypress, ui-testing

I have a following test in Cypress:

- visit first page with the header `A`
- click on the `Go to B Page` button
- assert that the header of the page is now `B`

It works fine in Chrome, but failing in Firefox, as on the page `B` I have some background polling requests, and when cypress switches to another test and those requests get "canceled" away, I get either `TypeError: NetworkError when attempting to fetch resource` or `AbortError: The operation was aborted`

All the requests are using fetch api, by the way.

The possibility to mute those errors through the `uncaught:exception` event seems a bad idea, and so does the idea to do something on the page to cancel the polling, as it is not the thing under testing.

Maybe someone has encoutnered this problem too and got some non-hacky solution?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue with Cypress tests in Firefox and resorted to the slightly hacky solution of using an `uncaught:exception` handler as you mention. It is possible to filter error messages somewhat at least:

```js
  function handleUncaughtException(err){
    if (err.message.includes('Request aborted') ) {
        console.log("Request aborted. Test will continue. Error:",err);
        return false;   // return false to make test continue
    }
    throw err;
  }
  cy.on('uncaught:exception',handleUncaughtException);
```

In principle you can cancel this handler when it's no longer needed. In my case though, this stopped the test working, presumably because the request started previous to or after the calls.

```js
cy.removeListener("uncaught:exception",  handleUncaughtException)
```

The Cypress docs have some advice on defining these: see at https://docs.cypress.io/api/events/catalog-of-events#Examples. It may be useful to put the handler in a support file, so that it is applied to all tests.

(See also https://docs.cypress.io/api/events/catalog-of-events#Event-Types and https://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_removelistener_eventname_listener).